# Find shortest road(s) connecting any 2 pair of points

Tags: python, osmnx

I have a shapefile containing road network information and a list of lat lon points (shown in red in map). The points are not guaranteed to lie on a road.

I want to find the shortest road connecting any 2 pair of points and plot that road in a map. How can I do that?

The list of points (longitude, latitude) is as follows:

```
[[25.57925464 48.22272015]
 [30.07394513 49.20624044]
 [24.71950258 49.29032059]
 [28.18076493 49.84160442]
 [22.64412428 48.46259112]
 [25.66738199 48.66065565]
 [25.60755477 48.36588896]
 [30.07236379 49.18836981]
 [28.11408613 49.84760507]
 [30.07152161 49.18863373]
 [24.72089181 49.29014694]
 [24.98422959 48.69505224]
 [22.64554781 48.46238204]
 [32.34790009 48.47251886]
 [30.21000526 48.94404358]
 [25.5806167  48.22461814]
 [24.71188577 49.29464777]
 [30.07581965 49.20389477]
 [30.07527381 49.18857539]
 [31.36285513 49.3070935 ]
 [32.34209481 48.4793055 ]
 [28.68966268 49.13953097]
 [28.11572736 49.84822564]
 [31.1910739  48.59072315]
 [26.8153163  48.85545504]
 [25.6630429  48.34444028]
 [24.89757249 48.7625933 ]
 [24.71154061 49.29478723]
 [25.6682908  48.66009589]
 [25.66472488 48.6610783 ]
 [31.37621921 49.32160973]
 [32.39707855 51.24104624]
 [31.3429478  51.11037809]
 [28.69020289 49.13702762]
 [25.66292554 48.34328093]
 [28.70593533 49.11971917]
 [25.66954126 48.659588  ]
 [31.7971185  48.21618349]
 [32.32701329 48.46917026]
 [28.03302836 49.33822554]
 [24.89234006 48.76446997]
 [26.81222988 48.8546306 ]
 [25.60984975 48.36571544]
 [28.02327843 49.33662326]
 [24.98381373 48.69454483]
 [30.21105788 48.94595284]
 [31.36002599 49.32395471]
 [28.70703167 49.11916411]
 [32.3266258  48.46759114]
 [28.11179067 49.8483458 ]
 [31.19093051 48.58989204]
 [32.33653923 48.47028404]]
```

Comment: Cool! Good luck.

Comment: If a point isn't on a road, how can any road connect?

Comment: And, whats the question? Do you expect any of us to implement this for you? Well... i don't think so :-)

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  POstin ga partial problem statement is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import osmnx as ox
list_coords = [(25.57925464 48.22272015),(30.07394513 49.20624044)]
p1 = list_coords[0]
p2 = list_coords[1]

import geopandas
gdf_nodes = geopandas.read_file('nodes.shp') #shapefiles that you have
gdf_edges = geopandas.read_file('edges.shp') #shapefiles that you have
G = ox.gdfs_to_graph(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges)

node1 = ox.get_nearest_node(G,p1) #to get node on the graph nearest to the point p1
node2 = ox.get_nearest_node(G,p2) #to get node on the graph nearest to the point p2

import networkx as nx
route = nx.shortest_path(G, node1, node2, weight='length') #obtain shortest path based on length
route_length = nx.shortest_path_length(G, node1, node2, weight='length') #obtain shortest path length
```